# How to center list items with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position, navbar, centering

I am trying to create a navbar with heading on the left, and list items centered. I used flexbox to horizontally line links. Then ı added `margin: auto` to ul which moved them to left but did'nt centered them symetrically. I am guessing there is no space for the ul to move anymore. I checked other similiar posts but couldn't quite figure what the problem is. Thank you for your time.

HTML

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 1.6;
    background: url('/img/showcase.jpg.jpg');
}


#navbar  {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
}

#navbar ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Please edit your code so it includes the relevant issues only

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by edit your code? I have alredy no idea what the relevant issues are.

Comment: width:100% to ul?

Comment: it only put a space between anchors, making the distance between each anchor huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question (please, let me know), this is what you're after:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  background: url('/img/showcase.jpg.jpg');
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#navbar,
#navbar ul {
  display: flex;
}

#navbar {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#navbar ul {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what ı am looking for. I am guessing ı couldn't explain my problem properly. What ı want to do is, treat both logo and list items individually. I'd like to center list items on the navbar. After that, place the logo on the left side of the navbar.  In your code snippet, logo is on the left that's okay but list items still a little on the right. Sorry if ı make it complicated.

Comment: @Akın Uçar Help us to help you: try to make an image of what you want to achieve. That's the only way.

Comment: @Akın Uçar I see all grey. There's no image.

Comment: https://imgbox.com/SRSxLoE2 could you try this please?

Comment: @Akın Uçar I've edited my answer. Let me know.

Comment: The list items still look like they are not centered. However, removing logo from the navbar, centers the list items exactly how ı want. Here is an image showing how. https://imgbox.com/ZQZ2BUbz

Comment: @Akın Uçar If you watch the code snippet on full page, you'll notice that the list is perfectly centered: i.e. there's the same space between the logo and the right side of navbar (like in your first image). This is how flexbox works. Obviously, if you remove the logo, the list get centered rispect to entire navbar,

Answer (score 1):

You could remove  `margin: 0 auto;` from `#navbar ul`

The flexbox on the parent container ( `#navbar` ) is already centering the `ul`. Adding `margin: 0 auto` to it after adding flexbox breaks the layout.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background: url('/img/showcase.jpg.jpg');
}
#navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
}
#navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  /* margin: 0 auto; REMOVE THIS LINE */
  padding: 0;
}
#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Also, it might yeild better results to include your logo as a list item:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background: url('/img/showcase.jpg.jpg');
}
#navbar, li { /* added flex to li's so content stays vertically centered */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
}
#navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  /* margin: 0 auto; REMOVE THIS LINE */
  padding: 0;
}
#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px; /* fixed vertical padding to 0 from 20px */
  background-color: transparent; /* Added for continuity with your design */
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class='logo'>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**If you would like to add space between the logo and the list items you can add `margin-right: ( n )` to the logo itself. See below:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background: url('/img/showcase.jpg.jpg');
}
#navbar, li { /* added flex to li's so content stays vertically centered */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
}
#navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  /* margin: 0 auto; REMOVE THIS LINE */
  padding: 0;
}
#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px; /* fixed vertical padding to 0 from 20px */
  background-color: transparent; /* Added for continuity with your design */
}
.logo { /* Added space between logo and list items */
  margin-right: 5rem; /* you can add units in pixels as well if you would like */
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class='logo'>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Notice no matter how much or how little margin you add to `.logo` everything automatically stays centered.

Comment: Removing margin: 0 auto;  from #navbar ul also removed the distance between logo and list items and centered everything on the line. When ı tried to move logo to left, it also pushed list items to right. Also, if ı include my logo as a list items, how is it going to be possible to place it on the left individually?

Comment: If you would like to add more distance between the logo and the list items you can add a right margin to the logo. I'm including in an edit.

Comment: Sorry but problem still remains same. I copied exactly what you changed and list items still looks like they are not centered. İf ı add margin-right to logo and move it to the left, it goes off the page when ı minimize the window.

Comment: You didn’t copy my code correctly then. Look at the latest code snippet to my answer. All of my code above is running live in the browser. Eveything looks centered to me - if not please specify in better detail what it is you are trying to achieve. Also you could use a percentage for the margin instead of a fixed width like pixels. Or you could even add margin right to the list container instead of directly on the logo if you’re experiencing issues in your local code. However, there are better ways to do what you are trying to achieve. if I have the time I’ll re write everything for you.